# Single Widget Multi Sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I wrote a widget that has multiple output format based on type dropdown list. I intend to use this widget on both left and right sidebars. The problem however is it only shows up on one sidebar either left or right. I want the widget to appear on both sidebars
please find the widget code below:

```
 class Posts_Widgets extends WP_Widget{

  function __construct(){
    $id = "posts_widgets";
    $name = "Anzima Posts Widgets";
    $widgets_ops = array('description'=>__('Widget for displaying various posts formats'));
    $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 350);
    parent::__construct($id,$name,$widgets_ops);
  }

  function form($instance){
    $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
    $cats  = esc_attr($instance['cats']);
    $type  = esc_attr($instance['type']);
    ?>
         <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" ><?php _e('Title'); ?>:
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" 
              name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title');?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title);?>" />
            </label>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cats'); ?>" ><?php _e('Post Categories'); ?>:
            <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cats'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cats')?>" >
            <?php $cats_a = $this->get_category(); ?>
            <option value="" ><?php _e('Please select an option'); ?></option>
            <option value="x" <?php if($cats == 'x'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?> ><?php _e('Most Read'); ?></option>
            <?php foreach($cats_a as $o){ ?>
                <option <?php if($cats == $o->id){?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="<?php echo $o->id; ?>"><?php echo $o->name; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </label>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('type'); ?>" ><?php _e('Display Type'); ?>:
            <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('type'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('type')?>" >
               <option value="" ><?php _e('Please select an option'); ?></option>
               <option <?php if($type == 1){?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="1" ><?php echo _e('Main Plus Thumbs List'); ?></option>
               <option <?php if($type == 2){?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="2" ><?php echo _e('Item List'); ?></option>
               <option <?php if($type == 3){?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="3" ><?php echo _e('Main Plus List'); ?></option>
               <option <?php if($type == 4){?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="4" ><?php echo _e('Grid'); ?></option>
               <option <?php if($type == 5){?>selected="selected"<?php }?> value="4" ><?php echo _e('Single Post'); ?></option>
            </select>
            </label>
         </p>
    <?php 
  }

  function update($new_instance,$old_instance){
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
    $instance['cats'] = strip_tags($new_instance['cats']);
    $instance['type'] = strip_tags($new_instance['type']);
   return $instance;
  }

  function widget($args, $instance) {
      extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
      $data = array();
      if($instance['cats'] != 'x'){
        $data['title'] = get_cat_name($instance['cats']);
        $data['image'] = ((is_file(TEMPLATEPATH . '/images/'.$instance['cats'].'.png'))?get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/'.$instance['cats'].'.png':'');
      }else{
        $data['title'] = 'most read';
        $data['image'] = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/most-read.png';
      }
      $data['id'] = $instance['cats'];
      $data['list'] = $this->get_list($instance['cats'],$instance['type']);
      include_once TEMPLATEPATH . '/widgets/templates/'.$instance['type'].'.php';
  }
  }
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your utterly appreciated help

---

FlashingCursor; I am registering the widget just forgot to paste it

```
function reg_post_widget(){
register_widget( 'Posts_Widgets' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init','reg_post_widget');
```

The problem is it appears only on onside bar but not both although in the backend I can drop the widget on both sidebars

---

Thank you for your response, I am registering my widget but forgot to paste it The problem however, is that the widget only appears on one sidebar either left or right but not both at a time. I don't know if I am missing some configuration option to make my widget multi-widget. Definitely I am missing something out!!! by the way how can I reply to answers instead of editing them??

Comment: You ended up with two different accounts on site, I merged them. You should now be able to edit your question and leave comments on answers for it ("add comment" below them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after looking at wp_option tables for my widget and the sidebars_widget option I figured out that my widget name has to be none white space separated, in my case it should be anzima_posts_widgets, also I have to include the base-id in the control_ops parameter as the first index.

Another issue I figured out that made look silly!!! is that I am having include_once for my html template files.

I am really glad that I figured it out